# Google analytics campaign unique visitors

Tags: google-analytics

I send newsletters from my Drupal-7 website and I want to track unique users who clicked on my newsletter's link. Currently, what I implement is adding

```
?utm_source=test&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=test
```

at every link of my newsletter, change test with the name of my campaign and check my Google Analytics on Acquisition - Campaigns - All Campaigns.
From that I get the number of the clicks that my links got, but I assume that if a user clicked twice on a link, then the counter is increased by 2.
Is there a way to achieve unique visitor count for my campaign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the data in terms of unique landing page visits instead of sessions. This will give you unique pageviews.

To do this, create a custom segment for your source/medium/campaign, then navigate to Behavior > Site Content > Landing Pages.

Here you can view unique pageviews to your campaign's landing page.

Comment: why not just look at the users metric? Have I really misunderstood this question?

Comment: The campaign view only gives a new users metric which is not really the same as users

Comment: Then you can easily do a custom report selecting users as a metric and campaign as a dimension.   
Customisation > New Report.   
  That way if your campaign spans more than one landing page you can still get the number of users.

Comment: Yeah true. I was thinking more ad hoc, but for easily tracking multiple LPs over time, a custom report would be ideal

Comment: @JoeLaw I know how to track how many users clicked on my links, my question is about uniqueness. I want to be able to tell that 10 different users clicked on my links, rather than "my link got clicked 30 times" for example

Comment: @CatherineSmith where exactly is the unique pageviews? in which column/field?

Comment: Users is the metric you are after then. You'll notice it should be a lower value than sessions or pageviews.   
http://analytive.com/blog/differences-users-sessions-pageviews-google-analytics-update/